# Java - Make a library class comparable

Tags: java, comparator, comparable, anonymous-class

Is it possible to make library classes comparable without extending them?

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

LinkedList<JSONObject> list = getListFromFunction();

TreeSet<JSONObject> treeSet = new TreeSet<JSONObject>(list);
```

Making a `TreeSet` here is not possible as `JSONObject` is not comparable. How can I "attach" a custom comparator to `JSONObject`?
 *(There is a unique property, say "_some_id" to compare with)*

Comment: Why not pass in a `Comparator`?  (Really, that's the only option you've got.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use Comparator in such a case and handle the scenario. Please refer the below example.

**Main Class**

```
public class ComparatorTest{
     public static void main(String[] ar) {
        // System.out.println(new Sample().stringTimes("vivek", 5));
        JSONObject emp1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject emp2 = new JSONObject();
        try {
            emp1.put("department", "IT");
            emp1.put("name", "bvivek");
            emp1.put("id", 1);

            emp2.put("department", "IT");
            emp2.put("name", "avikash");
            emp2.put("id", 2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<JSONObject> employess = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        employess.add(emp1);//add to list
        employess.add(emp2);//add to list
        System.out.println(employess);//unsorted, as is
        Collections.sort(employess, new JSONComparator("name"));
        System.out.println(employess);//sorted as per the field
        //using treeSet
        TreeSet<JSONObject> jsonInTree = new TreeSet<JSONObject>(new JSONComparator("id"));
        jsonInTree.addAll(employess);
        System.out.println(jsonInTree);//using the tree implementation
    }
}
```

**JSONComparator**

```
class JSONComparator implements Comparator<JSONObject> {
    private String fieldToCompare;

    public JSONComparator(String fieldToCompare) {
        this.fieldToCompare = fieldToCompare;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) {
        String id1 = "";
        String id2 = "";
        try {
            id1 = o1.getString(this.fieldToCompare);
            id2 = o2.getString(this.fieldToCompare);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

        return id1.compareTo(id2);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I insert the say sorted result in to a TreeSet which allows comparable objects only

Comment: You can do so by creating the treeset using the comparator and then adding all the elements to treeset. Please refer my updated answer for same.

Comment: Thanks.I was confused with C++ syntax for custom comparators

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do something like this will work for any classes that aren't comparable. The way you do this is by creating your own comparing method, you can do this in a way like:

```
public static int compareJSONObjects(JSONObject obj1, JSONObject obj2){
    if(obj1.getField()>obj2.getField()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

now when you call list.sort() you can create your own Comparator like this:

```
list.sort( (obj1, obj2) -> compareJSONObject(obj1, obj2) );
```

by doing this you cut down on the amount of lines required, as this entire thing could be shortened to 1 line by using [ternary](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) and doing:

```
list.sort( (obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getField()>obj2.getField() ? 1 : -1 );
```